# Maven multimodule project with Jenkins and git

Tags: maven, jenkins

Currently we have a number of maven projects (specifically Apache Camel) that reside in isolation. We also have one Jenkins job per project because we need to specify the pom.xml file in the maven build and since the projects are independent then we require one job per project.

However, we also know most of the projects share a lot of dependencies and we want to turn them into a maven multi-module project with a parent pom file where the dependencies and versions are stated. We also want to have fewer Jenkins jobs to maintain and allow more projects to be added without having to create new Jenkins job.

My question is, in the Jenkins job for the maven build I still need to specify a single pom file. Does this mean that I need to point to the parent pom file and then add theparent directory as the directory to for Jenkins to receive the git trigger? In a sense, whenever a code is committed to any of the child projects, the job gets triggered and it uses the parent pom file to build only that project where the code was committed?

Comment: You can configure Jenkins to launch the build only on changed module, yes, using an incremental build, make sure you use up-to-date versions of both Jenkins and Maven. You would still point Jenkins at the parent POM (always).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip, I'll have to test this then.